# How to get Most Commented using Facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

We currently Facebook comments on our website and we are looking to make a "Most Commented" widget. We would like to display a list of headlines that have received the most comments in the last 24 hours.

Is it possible to query the "most commented" or "most shared" stories for our website within a given time frame using Facebook's open graph or any of their other tools?

We currently use `http://graph.facebook.com/?callback=?&ids=' + someURL;` to get data on an individual story such as comment count and how many shares, but I have been unable to find a way that lets me get information on all of my pages at one time and do any advanced filtering.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this FQL query to get the like count, comment count, share count etc for any external links.

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://google.com%27&format=json
```

You get a response like :

> [{"total_count":5189603,"like_count":986662,"comment_count":1125601,"share_count":3077340,"click_count":265614}]

which you can json_decode. Or if you want it xml, remove the `format=json` from the query string.

So what I have now in mind is keeping a track of all the counts of all your urls and periodically update them to get the most liked,shared urls etc.